# How to create comma separated list from nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having little bit of confusion in this array..

Actually I'm having an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1
            [food_item] => Chicken Spicy Pizza
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1
            [food_item] => Pepper Chicken Sandwich
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 6
            [food_item] => Chicken Tikka Roll
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 6
            [food_item] => Grilled Chicken
        )

)
```

Here I need to create a comma separated value of `food_item` And also there must be a condition the array having same `restaurant_id` also merged..

i.e;..

My final Array should be like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 1
            [food_item] => Chicken Spicy Pizza,Pepper Chicken Sandwich
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [restaurant_id] => 6
            [food_item] => Chicken Tikka Roll,Grilled Chicken
        )
)
```

Any Suggestions?!!...

Thank you!.

Comment: What you have tried? Suggestion based on your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-reduce.php) to accomplish it

```
$myArr = array_reduce($myArr, function ($carry, $item) {
    if (!isset($carry[$item->restaurant_id])) {
        $carry[$item->restaurant_id] = $item;
    } else {
        $carry[$item->restaurant_id]->food_item .= ',' . $item->food_item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, array());
```

Comment: Thank you Matei Mihai for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Let your actual array is in a variable called `$actualArr`. So here is the code

```
        $actualArr = array(
        (object) array('restaurant_id' => 1, 'food_item' => 'Chicken Spicy Pizza'),
        (object) array('restaurant_id' => 1, 'food_item' => 'Pepper Chicken Sandwich'),
        (object) array('restaurant_id' => 6, 'food_item' => 'Chicken Tikka Roll'),
        (object) array('restaurant_id' => 6, 'food_item' => 'Grilled Chicken'),
    );



$newArr = array();
foreach($actualArr as $value){
    $newArr[$value->restaurant_id][] = $value->food_item;
}

$finalArr = array();

foreach($newArr as $key => $value){
   $finalArr[] = (object) array('restaurant_id' => $key, 'food_item' => implode(',', $value));
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArr);
```

Here is the code Link

http://pastebin.com/RvjQ3Edj

Comment: @ Md. Sahadat Hossain Thank you so much I got it finally.. :)